# FindFragmentById returns null even with container id

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I have an activity whose sole purpose is to show 5 different fragments in a frame layout. There are 5 buttons, each corresponding to one of the 5 fragments that can be displayed in the frame layout.

I'm trying to make it so that the activity doesn't respond to a button press of the button that corresponds to the SAME fragment, so that there are no animations or other unnecessary computation performed.

The problem is that BOTH `findFragmentById` and `findFragmentByTag` return null, even when *I believe* I'm passing in the correct parameter of the `container view`, i.e. the frame layout.

Here is how I dynamically switch the fragments when responding to button presses:

```
    private void viewProfile(){
    profile_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment profile = new ProfileFragment();
            beginFragment(profile, "profile");
        }
    });
}
    private void beginFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
            android.R.animator.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_display, fragment, tag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to determine what fragment is being displayed in the container:

```
    private void launchEvents(){
    final Fragment current_frag = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_display);
    events_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!current_frag.getTag().equals("events")) {
                Fragment events = new EventsFragment();
                beginFragment(events, "events");
                events.setArguments(location_info);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my XML file, in case I'm getting something wrong with the layout hierarchy:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#323272"
tools:context=".HomeScreen">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="527dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:background="#323272:color/background_dark">

</FrameLayout>
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be great! I feel so silly for being stuck on something so minor.

Comment: Your code is not complete. it is not clear if you created and attached a fragment before you tried to replace it via `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_display, fragment, tag);` Furthermore, your xml doesn't include a fragment definition (see the xml here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating). Notice in your code you are trying to retrieve a fragment by id, BUT the id belongs to a FrameLayout element? Consider checking some examples first to learn core concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Move you `findFragmentById` in `onClick` methods as below and instant of checking a tag check the `instanceof`  if fragment

```
  private void launchEvents(){

        events_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Fragment current_frag = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_display);
                if (!(current_frag  instanceof EventsFragment)) {
                    Fragment events = new EventsFragment();
                    beginFragment(events, "events");
                    events.setArguments(location_info);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: God bless you. Does something about the "final" type mess things up?

Comment: No,when you click button you have got old value of fragment because you code is for find a fragment in outside a fragment and it will not executed on clicking a button so it always return old value

Comment: Ah!! Thanks so much.